# Does Wordpress support opening multiple post through the 'Quick Edit' link?

Tags: wordpress

There is a needed feature where clicking one post using the 'Quick Edit' should not 'force close' other posts already opened. But I think, there is no possible way to do this at the moment because the inlineEditPost object only accepts an 'id' parameter. I came to this conclusion for I have done a custom hook recently - that shows the fields of a custom post in the 'Quick Edit' area.

How can I support this claim? I have no strong reference/documentation to present for this?